# Magento Subcategories issues

Tags: magento, categories

Hello I Need to get parent category id of sub category. If I am in a sub category page i need the id of its parent category so that i could do some modification on my code to display the sub categories in my way. Please help me doing so. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

$parent_id = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getParentCategory()->getId();

echo $parent_id;

This will do.

Comment: Thanks satish thank u very much it did the trick & i got my parent id now.

Comment: Hello satish i am getting nothing with this as i have modified some codes over categories & now i am getting the categories through this :<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getId(); ?>  but it is only displaying root category id every time could you tell me why is it so ?? and thanks for the reply again

Comment: 1. If you look at the above code I stated.You get current category and then parent category from current category in your case you have no code for parent category.So add some code for parent category